# List all parameters in AWS SSM Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ssm

How do I list all parameters in the AWS Systems Manager (SSM) Parameter Store? I am using the AWS CLI.

I can store them with `aws ssm put-parameter`. I can fetch them with `aws ssm get-parameter`. I can list all documents with `aws ssm list-documents`, but I do not see a corresponding `list-parameters` function.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
    aws ssm describe-parameters
```

[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-parameters.html)

Answer (score 11):

If you need to list parameters' name and know the path you could use the following:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
    --path "/my-common-path" \
    --recursive \
    --query "Parameters[*].Name"
```

See AWS cli v2 docs for more info: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters-by-path.html

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [describe-parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ssm/describe-parameters.html).