# How to find parameter in AWS Parameterstore?

Tags: aws-parameter-store

How to find parameter values recursively from all the parameters. We have around 1000 parameters and from this how can I find which database is used in which project.

Thanks,

Comment: would this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011890/list-all-parameters-in-aws-ssm-parameter-store

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Using describe-parameters I am not able to find the values from parameter store. Basically I am looking for how to find values from parameter store same link find command in linux. 

Thanks,

Comment: I think you might have to first get all parameters, then iterate on each to get their values.  Using GetParametersByPath